# How to write custom CSS for gmail add ons?

Tags: css, google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I would like to override the default material design and provide a set of custom styles. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Addons do not have access to styles defined by Google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following [HTML tags](https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/concepts/widgets#text_formatting) are supported for text widgets inside Gmail add-ons. You cannot apply custom styles to any other element inside add-ons. [image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for this by using a Chrome extension in tandem with the add-on. Great resource for template Chrome extensions is https://extensionizr.com/. Just add your custom CSS and/or JS into the extension, enable permissions, and you're good to go.

Comment: But it does not talk anything about gmail addons. Have you tried this yourself ?